# Building a reliable system on Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

Stack Overflow community who use Google AppEngine,

Given the reliability issues with Google AppEngine, how are you handling fail-over to prevent outages?  Are you doing a back-up mirror on another platform?

Is there a way to make your instance 'hot-swappable' to avoid issues?  Anyone come up with elegant solutions to avoid Service Issues?

Comment: Note that the latest outage did not only affect AppEngine, but other large service providers. Since the problem was in routers and it affected different service providers, we can only speculate that this was some kind of targeted attack against a particular model/version of routers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an AppEngine, you domain resolves to AppEngine's IP address. In case of an outage you will have to change the DNS record, and it will take hours for it to propagate through the DNS servers. By that time it's likely that the AppEngine is already restored, and now you have to change the DNS record again - and add a few more hours of confusion/downtime for your users. This means that backups of data are good for end-of-the-Google or legal contingencies, but they are not very useful for short outages. Besides, with data backups you always have some data loss, unless you make backups continuously in real-time, which is either impossible or very taxing on your system, not to mention it may degrade user experience through longer response times.

Unless your app already makes millions of dollars in revenue each day, the cost of building a solution that can switch very quickly (minutes) to a totally different platform without any data loss is prohibitively high. Hint: many well-known services, employing many talented engineers, went down during the AppEngine outage.